# What to choose cloud Functions or Database for a Quiz app

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a quiz app, that uses a Firestore document called Question which looks like
[image]

Now whenever a quiz is loaded this data is loaded from firestore, question is displayed and answer is checked against the 'answer' field. Now any mischievous programmer can change the client code to see all the answers to questions and may win the contest (Contest winners are paid). One way of preventing this is by removing the answer field and creating a new document of answers and using cloud functions to check right answers. Which can increase the billing since each user may invoke thousands of function calls.

Is there any approach to address this issue, if not which is the better approach

1. Checking answers with cloud functions
2. Creating a separate collection of answers

Comment: Why now securing your database using [Cloud Firestore Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started)?

Answer (score 0):

The data will only be safe if it's not acessible by the user, you could try to secure it by using either:

- Different documents representing questions and answers;
- Keeping everything in the same collection and cotrolling access with the firebase rules, as exemplified in this [community answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47288802/12857703);
- Using two different Cloud Functions to fetch the same document as a question and an answer and transform then into different json responses depending on which stage of the execution you are in;

All of those option will increase your costs, as the data will be read more than once and there are cloud functions costs involved as well as unfortunately it is what is.

I would advice you to try going for either the first or the second approach, as they are both safe options for what you are trying to achieve and would cost you less than the third option.